# cron не хочет работать

Tags: linux, cron

Добрый вечер.
Настроил задание в /etc/cron.d/upload:

```
    5   4   *    *   *      root    python /var/www/webapps/mysite.ru/upload.py > /dev/null 2>&1
    5   5   *    *   *      root    python /var/www/webapps/mysite.biz/upload.py > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему он не хочет работать (в конце файла есть пустая строка, вроде где то было написано что должно быть). ОС debian, машину перезагружал. В логах:

```
    May  8 04:54:31 hs-python anacron[526]: Anacron 2.3 started on 2016-05-08
    May  8 04:54:31 hs-python anacron[526]: Will run job `cron.daily' in 5 min.
    May  8 04:54:31 hs-python anacron[526]: Will run job `cron.weekly' in 10 min.
    May  8 04:54:31 hs-python anacron[526]: Will run job `cron.monthly' in 15 min.
    May  8 04:54:31 hs-python anacron[526]: Jobs will be executed sequentially
    May  8 04:59:31 hs-python anacron[526]: Job `cron.daily' started
    May  8 04:59:38 hs-python anacron[526]: Job `cron.daily' terminated
    May  8 05:04:31 hs-python anacron[526]: Job `cron.weekly' started
    May  8 05:04:31 hs-python anacron[526]: Job `cron.weekly' terminated
    May  8 05:09:31 hs-python anacron[526]: Job `cron.monthly' started
    May  8 05:09:31 hs-python anacron[526]: Job `cron.monthly' terminated
    May  8 05:09:31 hs-python anacron[526]: Normal exit (3 jobs run)
```

Comment: 1. процесс *cron* вообще запущен? 2. что-нибудь тестовое (типа `touch /tmp/somefile`) выполняется?

Comment: Пропишите полный путь к питону

Comment: Тестовое задание не отработало. Полный путь прописал.

Comment: повтор вопроса: процесс cron вообще запущен?

Comment: не подскажите как проверить?! )

Answer (score 2):

Следует убедиться, что процесс cron запущен, например при помощи команды ps

```
ps uax | grep cron
```

если в процессах его нет, попробуйте его стартануть

```
/etc/init.d/cron start
```

если в процессах он наблюдается, попробуйте рестартануть

```
/etc/init.d/cron restart
```